# deploying nextjs export files to Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js

I have trouble trying to host my nextjs export files on Amazon S3. Has anybody done this before? CSS styling doesn't seem to take effect after I upload my files to the bucket. I made the entrypoint index.html on S3. This is my folder structure for my exported nextjs files:

[image]

My css and js files can be found in the _next folder as shown:

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!